# iAd not displaying on XCode 4.0.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, iad

I am trying to add iAds in my existing Iphone application. I have implemented everything by following: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app
but the ads do not show up in my app. I am using XCode 4.0.1 and iOS 4.3.3.

I can't even run the example given on that link. When I run my existing code on XCode 3.x version everything works fine and ads show up correctly.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem with Xcode 4.0.1 version ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean test ads? They quite often do not show up - sometimes rebooting the device, or reinstalling the app helps. Or try on a different device.

Comment: I have tried with different devices as well. It works fine with previous version of XCode but just not with XCode 4.0.1

Comment: If you are sure that you have done everything correctly, consider tweeting Ray or commenting on the post - he tends to reply very promptly to feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my XCode and it solved the issue. May be it was a bug with XCode